# Use an array as argv?

Tags: bash, scripts

In a bash script, I'm calling a function with a large number of arguments, say for example `/bin/meaningoflife` takes 42 arguments. Is there a way I can pass an array to a command instead of manually entering in all of the 42 arguments? For example:

```
arr = ("arg1", "arg2", "arg3")
/bin/meaningoflife {argv=arr}
```

is the same as

```
/bin/meaningoflife "arg1" "arg2" "arg3"
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The bash syntax would be

```
arr=("arg1" "arg2" "arg3")          # no commas, no whitespace around the assignment
/bin/meaningoflife "${arr[@]}"      # double quotes prevent word splitting of elements
```

More formally, rather than "no commas" in the assignment, you want array elements to be separated by whitespace. It would be equally valid to write

```
arr=(
  "arg1"
  "arg2"
  "arg3"
)
```

for example - which is often easier to read for long lists.

See [Arrays (Bash Reference Manual)](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Arrays.html#index-arrays)

Comment: Even if IFS is set to comma, that only affects word splitting after variable expansion, not when parsing the script source itself.

Comment: @Barmar thanks - for some reason, I was thinking IFS affected the parsing of the compound assignment

Comment: Thanks, this is review i was meaning to get into for a while, i haven't used arrays in bash for nearly 20 years!!